# Архивация веток git/GitHub

Tags: git, github, контроль-версий

Есть ли в git или хотя бы GitHub возможность отправлять старые и неиспользуемые ветки куда-то в архив?

Допустим, я создал ветку для добавления какой-то новой возможности в мой проект. Затем, реализовав эту возможность, я сливаю эту ветку в master. Теперь эта ветка мне больше не нужна, однако я не хочу её удалять в целях сохранения истории развития проекта. Но и видеть её в списке веток я тоже не хочу.

- Есть ли возможность как-то отметить такую ветку как архивную, чтобы
  она не отображалась в списке веток?
- И вообще, можно ли группировать ветки по категориям? Чтобы можно было легко видеть какие ветки архивные, какие проходят тестирование, какие в разработке и т.д.

Comment: просто ставить им `tag` не вариант?

Comment: @Fat-Zer можете подробнее объяснить как применить для этих целей теги?

Comment: `git tag archive/good-old-branch good-old-branch && git branch -d good-old-branch` ну и, по необходимости, `git push origin :good-old-branch && git push origin archive/good-old-branch`

Comment: "я не хочу её удалять в целях сохранения истории развития проекта" - но вы ведь слили всё в мастер, и вся история теперь есть там, зачем хранить исходную ветку?